# Connection in Singapore between Jetstar Asia and Finnair. Can I remain in the international transit area?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, singapore, connecting-flights

I am currently looking at a flight on the Finnair website which has two layovers. Route is DRW -> SIN -> HEL -> TLV, so from Darwin, Australia to Tel Aviv, Israel. The return route is the reverse (TLV -> HEL -> SIN -> DRW). The DRW -> SIN and SIN -> DRW legs are with Jetstar Asia. All other flights are with Finnair.

The question is about the connection logistics in Singapore. I have connected in Singapore in the past but with other airlines (full-service ones). Mainly because Jetstar Asia is a low-cost carrier, I am wondering whether I will be able to stay in the international transit area or would need to clear immigration.

The itinerary is offered on the Finnair website and the code for the flight operated by Jetstar Asia appears as "AY", so it seems to be a code-share.

So to be more specific, I'll be grateful if someone could help me with the following related questions:

1. For the outgoing route, in case Jetstar Asia does not give me all boarding passes when I check in at DRW, when I get to SIN from DRW and transfer onward to HEL, will I be able to get a boarding pass at a Finnair transfer counter at SIN and use that to board the plane for my next flight (without needing to clear immigration)?
2. For the incoming route, in case Finnair does not give me all boarding passes when I check in at TLV, when I get to SIN from HEL and transfer onward to DRW, will I be able to get a boarding pass at a Jetstar transfer counter at SIN and use that to board the plane for my next flight (without needing to clear immigration)?

P.S. I may making the assumption that when I disembark in Singapore Changi Airport (either when arriving from DRW or from HEL) I will get to the Departures area where all the gates are, which is what happened to me in the past when I arrived with full-service airlines.

Thank you very much for reading!

Answer (score 2):

If the trip is in a single booking, then yes, you can stay airside.

If it's in separate bookings, you cannot. As stated in Timatic, the database used by check-in staff:

> Transit passengers holding **2 separate tickets** can check in
>     for the connecting flight in the international transit area,
>     **except** when arriving/departing on a budget carrier. Budget
>     carriers are: Air Asia (AK), Indonesia AirAsia (QZ), Thai
>     AirAsia (FD), Air India Express (IX), Cebu Pacific Air (5J),
>     Firefly (FY), Jetstar (JQ), **Jetstar Asia (3K)**, Jetstar
>     Pacific (BL), Lion Air (JT), Scoot (TZ), Spring Airlines
>     (9C), Tigerair (TR) and VietJet Air (VJ).

Answer (score 0):

JetStar and Finnair are in the same terminal, T1. If JetStar had been in the LCC terminal, T3, that would have been a problem. Fortunately, JetStar and Finnair are [partners](http://www.jetstar.com/sg/en/help/articles/baggage-transfers), so with a single booking, your luggage will be transferred from JetStar to Finnair and vice-versa.

In Changi, you will have to find the proper transfer desk to get your next boarding pass(es).